# Getting and setting screen size for Xorg

Tags: command-line, xorg

I would like to run a command like `get-screen-resolution` during a **X session**  to get a '800x480' output. ( or whatever the actual screen size is ).

Is there something available for this? Currently I take a *screenshot* and measure the resulting `*.jpg`'s width & height attributes.

Also, how do I **set the screensize** during a X session from the command-line?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/418699/get-display-resolution-from-the-command-line-for-linux-desktop

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`xrandr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR) to do both

#### Get resolution

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
```

#### Set resolution

```
$ xrandr --output default --mode 1280x1024
```

Comment: If running `xrandr`over SSH, it is important to explicitly specify the display either by adding the parameter `--display 0` to your example, or by first setting the environment variable `export DISPLAY=0` before running your example. This is because the display cannot automatically be detected over SSH connections.

Comment: In my case, when running the command across a SSH PuTTY session to a Raspberry PI, I had to use:  xrandr --display :0.0

Answer (score 7):

From my personal shell library:

```
get_screen_size()
{
    xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions:/ { print $2; exit }'
}
```

Comment: In a multi-monitor setup this will show the dimensions of the bounding box which contains all monitors.

Answer (score 3):

## Clean `xrandr` output for imagemagick use

The following line takes the output of `xrandr` and cleans it with `awk` for use with imagemagick:

```
$ xrandr |awk '$0 ~ "*" {print $1}'

1366x768
```

Comment: Looks like you need `gawk`; `mawk` doesn't recognize that syntax

Comment: `xrandr | grep '*' | awk '{print $1}'` should work with any awk