# Is there a way to retrieve the name of the Desktop Environment?

Tags: command-line, desktop-environment

Is there a way to retrieve the desktop environment name (e.g. Gnome, Unity, XFCE, LXDE, KDE...) from the command line or using Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a Terminal input:

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

if it does not help (it may be equal 'default'), try

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

Comment: Note that this will not always work as sometimes DESKTOP_SESSION is set to "Default" or in some cases not set at all (I think it's gdm/kdm that set this variable). A better approach would be to check for the running session process.

Comment: I noticed there's also a varable XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="LXDE" (or "Unity", in my two desktops), do you think it's reliable?

Comment: @giuspen - discussed also here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235117/how-to-detect-if-linux-os-uses-kde-or-gnome-environment). XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP is just a proposal, it's not part of the XDG spec and is discussed on various mailing lists, e.g. [link](http://www.mail-archive.com/xdg@lists.freedesktop.org/msg06587.html). FIY I am on Gnome3/Arch64bit, I have all the xdg-* packages installed and this variable is unset.

Comment: @don_crissti - thanks I read in the other discussion that you linked that XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP is deprecated. I will try to look at the running processes.

Comment: @giuspen: On Xubuntu 13.04, I get `xubuntu` for `$DESKTOP_SESSION` and `XFCE` for `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`.