# How do I find the running GUI environment from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal, gui

It is a quite basic question, but I couldn't find a satisfying answer anywhere:

How do I find out from the terminal what is the running GUI?

---

The system I'm working on is quite minimal, all I can see are xterm windows, from where I can open applications (in separate windows). I can open new xterm window by right click in a free area on the desktop. Every time I open an application, and hence a new window, in order to actually open the window, I have to mouse click on a free area of the screen.

I don't think this question is a duplicate of [Is there a way to retrieve the name of the Desktop Environment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46305/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-name-of-the-desktop-environment), because my setup is a bit different than in that one, and none of its answers work for me.

Comment: DESKTOP_SESSION is not set. what does it mean to look for the running processes?

Comment: none of the answers provided work for me. the system I'm working on is quite minimal, all I can see are xterm windows, from where I can open applications (in separate windows). does it even qualify as desktop environment?

Comment: @don_crissti - there is no output

Comment: @don_crissti - neither

Comment: yes, it looks like that. so no GUI?

Comment: I am accessing this system through a vnc, and I would like to remap the keyboard shortcuts, because currently I am not able to switch between windows with Alt+tab. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 15):

You can type `env` to figure out what environments are configured.

The following response was found from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running)

```
  XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP - Tells you what Windows Manager you are using

  GDMSESSION - Tells you what option you selected from the lightdm greeter to login.
```

To use them, go to the terminal and type:

```
  echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

(Will output for example 'unity' if you are using Unity)

or

```
  echo $GDMSESSION
```

(Will output for example 'ubuntu' if you selected ubuntu in the login or 'ubuntu-2d' if you selected that one in the login.)

You have others if you look closer at the output of env like DESKTOP_SESSION and COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE

Since what you are looking for is the name of what Window Manager is in usem the only way I see how to get this is by looking in the process list. To do this there is a command called pgrep ( Wikipedia ). I did the following to get the name since the parameter -l adds the process ID:

`pgrep -l compiz |cut -d " " -f2` since the process is running by the same user there is no need to prefix the sudo part. You can then use this to create a script that does an action based on the Window Manager.

To look for other types, just change the word `compiz` to another like `mutter`, `kwin`, etc..

On Ubuntu 12.04 I tested environment variables XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP and GDMSESSION and got the following results:

**KDE**

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=
GDMSESSION=kde-plasma
Unity 3d

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
Unity 2d

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
GDMSESSION=ubuntu-2d

**Gnome**

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
GDMSESSION=gnome-shell

**Gnome Classic**

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
GDMSESSION=gnome-classic

**Gnome Classic no effects**

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
GDMSESSION=gnome-fallback
Other Ubuntu based distributions:

**Mint 13 (Cinnamon)**

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
GDMSESSION=cinnamon

**Lubuntu 12.04**

XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE
GDMSESSION=Lubuntu

Comment: If this question gets closed as a duplicate then you should copy your answer to the referenced question.